# How can I turn off scientific notation in ggplot2::cut_interval()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Usually `options(scipen = 999)` turns off scientific notation.  But I can't get it to work in `ggplot2::cut_interval()`.  How can I do that?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
options(scipen = 999) # disable scientific notation

# build example data frame
df <-
  data.frame(
    number = c(10047,439,111,10385,5,10384,10460)
  )

# create grouping variable
df %>% 
  mutate(
    grouping = cut_interval(number, length = 100, width = 1, center = 0) # don't want this to have scientific notation
  )
#>   number            grouping
#> 1  10047    (1e+04,1.01e+04]
#> 2    439           (400,500]
#> 3    111           (100,200]
#> 4  10385 (1.03e+04,1.04e+04]
#> 5      5             [0,100]
#> 6  10384 (1.03e+04,1.04e+04]
#> 7  10460 (1.04e+04,1.05e+04]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the argument `dig.lab = 5`

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(grouping = cut_interval(number, length = 100, width = 1, 
                                 center = 0, dig.lab = 5))
#>   number      grouping
#> 1  10047 (10000,10100]
#> 2    439     (400,500]
#> 3    111     (100,200]
#> 4  10385 (10300,10400]
#> 5      5       [0,100]
#> 6  10384 (10300,10400]
#> 7  10460 (10400,10500]
```

If you are uncertain how many digits your numbers will have, you can set the maximum `dig.lab` of 50 (a bit like setting scipen to 999)